# require() of ES Module ruta...\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js from ruta...\inquirer-autocomplete-prompt\index.js not supported

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

Tengo una app en ionic 7 y la estoy tratando de conectar con una base en firebase. Ya pude hacer el init sin problema y seleccionar mi proyecto, pero al ejecutar el comando `ng add @angular/fire` me muestra el siguiente error:

> require() of ES Module miRuta\node_modules\inquirer\lib\prompts\base.js from miRuta\node_modules\inquirer-autocomplete-prompt\index.js not supported.
> Instead change the require of base.js in miRuta\node_modules\inquirer-autocomplete-prompt\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Ya intenté varios cambios en el package.json y tambien en el tsconfig.json como lo siguiente:

```
  "type": "module",

    "module": "ESNext",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",

  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
```

entre otros y nada me ha dado solución; ya intenté con la versión 17 y 16 de angular fire y tampoco.

Comment: Verificaste que no haya incompatibilidad de versiones entre las dependencias? en tu caso en particular: inquirer e inquirer-autocomplete-prompt

Answer (score 0):

La solución es instalar/actualizar inquirer-autocomplete-prompt a la versión 3.0.1, lo puedes hacer con:

```
npm install inquirer-autocomplete-prompt@^3.0.1
```

Créditos a quien [contestó mi pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77776435/require-of-es-module-myroute-node-modules-inquirer-lib-prompts-base-js-not-sup/77779270#77779270)